# Kröger Vink notation

Tags: symbols, mhchem, chemistry

> **This question led to a new feature in a package:**
>   [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros)

How to properly typeset `Kröger Vink` notation?

I can try something like `\ce{V_O^{..}}` (using `mhchem`) but the dots are not aligned well and too thin. I tried googling it and I can see people have done it but not how.

Edit to add MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{O_O^x + Zn_{Zn}^x <-> 1/2 O2 + Zn_$i$^. + e^{-1}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: with version 4.5 (2014/04/08) `chemformula` has a basic native support for Kröger-Vink notation. It must be enabled with the option `kroeger-vink=true`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}[2014/04/08]

\begin{document}

\setchemformula{kroeger-vink}

\ch{Al_{Al}^x}

\ch{Ni_{Cu}^x}

\ch{V_{Cl}^{*}}

\ch{Ca_i^{**}}

\ch{e'}

\ch{Cl_i'}

\ch{O_i''}

\ch{O_O^x + Zn_{Zn}^x <-> 1/2 O2 + Zn_i^. + e^{-1}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Original answer:

I've never heard from the *Kröger Vink* notation before... but from what a [quick web search shows me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kr%C3%B6ger%E2%80%93Vink_notation) the following should be correct. I use `chemformula` (from the `chemmacros` bundle) because it let's you customize the size of the dots and the amount of horizontal shift of superscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\setchemformula{
  radical-radius = .3ex , % a larger `radical' dot
  charge-hshift  = 0pt    % don't shift superscripts to the right if subscripts
                          % are present
}

\ch{Al_{Al}^{$\times$}}

\ch{Ni_{Cu}^{$\times$}}

\ch{V_{Cl}^{.}}

\ch{Ca_i^{..}}

\ch{e^{$\prime$}}

\ch{Cl_i^{$\prime$}}

\ch{O_i^{$\prime\prime$}}

\ch{O_O^{$\times$} + Zn_{Zn}^{$\times$} <-> 1/2 O2 + Zn_i^. + e^{-1}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A question related to the “dot” symbol is [How to get the the dot symbol in Chemistry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158780/) which may give you some more hints

Comment: Just a small comment, though wikipedia gives the subscript i for interstitial as roman, it is more often seen as italic. ETA: I just checked IUPAC guide for nomenclature of inorganic chemistry and they use roman.

Comment: Then `_{$i$}` would do

Comment: @HenkMetselaar Roman does make more sense: italics usually denote variables

Answer (score 1):

When sticking with mhchem, simply swap `_` and `^`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{V^{..}_O}

\ce{O^x_O + Zn^x_{Zn} <-> 1/2 O2 + Zn^._i + e^{-1}}
\end{document}
```

As for the size of the dots, they are still relatively thin with mhchem. If you have a collection of text books from different publishers and they all agree that these dots should be bigger, then contact the author and he surely will update the package.